# SSIS - Retrieving result set values from Execute SQLTask to be used as parameters for Sybase Stored Proc

Tags: ssis, sap-ase

I am having troubles with running a Sybase ASE stored procedure, via an OLE DB Data source connection in a SSIS package that I am creating.  I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Data Services tools for VS 2012.

What I am doing is retrieving values via an Execute SQL task, taking the result set and setting them as variables and then using the variable as a parameter in the Data Source connection as part of a SQL Command that is calling an ASE stored procedure.

When I hard code the parameter values in the SQL command, everything seems to work fine.  When I change the command to use the newly mapped parameter, I get the following failure message:
Unable to retrieve column information from the data source.  Make sure your target table in the database is available.

In the ASE stored procedure, there is no default value set for the parameter.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this issue?  Is there something that I am missing in SSIS to get it to work?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check these options:

1. exec test  @[User::val1] , @[User::val2]
2. Store the variables into a tables and use the below command in sql command of oledb source:

declare @param1 int
declare @param2 int
select @param1 = val1 from param
select @param2 = val2 from param

exec test @param1,@param2

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried option 1, which didn't appear to work in the instance that I am working with.  I was going to try option 2, but I resolved my issue, by using SQL from variable.  I also got clouded by ASE not liking what SQL Server was assigning as a date value to a string...

Comment: Yes, the first option i provided was to be put into a variable and selected as SQLCommand from Variable. Since Sybase is being connected using a oledb driver, it does not really allow SSIS to identify the parameters. So its not as feasible as SQL. Thats Microsoft! :)